# diffrence from the max in each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['pt1','px1','t95','sx1','dc4','px5'],
'group':['f7','f7', 'f7','f8','f8','f8'],
'score':['2','3.3','4','8','4.9','6']})
```

I want to add another column and calculate the difference between each score in each group with the maximum score of that group. The expected result would be:

```
group id  score  score_diff
f7  pt1     2         -2
f7  px1   3.3        -.7
f7  t95     4          0
f8  sx1     8          0
f8  dc4   4.9        -3.1
f8  px5     6         -2
```

Would appreciate if you could please help. I want to run the code on 2000+ records. Below is my code but it gives me score difference from the previous record in each group. however, I want to calculate the score difference from max score in each group.

```
result = df.groupby(['fk'])['score'].diff()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to generate the `max` for each row of the dataframe, and then use simple substraction operation to get the desired output. Here's a working example.

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
  group   id score
0    f7  pt1     2
1    f7  px1   3.3
2    f7  t95     4
3    f8  sx1     8
4    f8  dc4   4.9
5    f8  px5     6

In[2]: df['score'] = df.score.astype(float)

In[3]: df['score_diff'] = df.score - df.groupby('group')['score'].transform('max')

In[4]: df
Out[4]: 
  group   id  score  score_diff
0    f7  pt1    2.0        -2.0
1    f7  px1    3.3        -0.7
2    f7  t95    4.0         0.0
3    f8  sx1    8.0         0.0
4    f8  dc4    4.9        -3.1
5    f8  px5    6.0        -2.0
```

---

Note:

- Please make sure that score column is a numeric (e.g: float), I used `df.score.astype(float)` to convert it to float.

Comment: Thanks MedAli for your answer. It solved my problem.